# Video discoloration after upload using ffmpeg in Twitter API

Tags: twitter, ffmpeg

What I'm trying to do is this - 
1) Take an image and audio, make it into a video using `ffmpeg`.(I am not well versed with `ffmpeg` but have a working command).
This is the command that I am using right now -

```
ffmpeg 
-y 
-loop 1 
-i <IMAGE> 
-i <SOUND> 
-vcodec libx264 
-vf 'scale=640:trunc(ow/a/2)*2' 
-acodec aac 
-strict experimental 
-vb 1024k
-minrate 1024k 
-maxrate 1024k 
-bufsize 1024k 
-ar 44100 
-shortest 
<OUTPUT-FILE>
```

2) Upload the video to Twitter, using it's API - [Uploading Chunked Media](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/public/uploading-media)

I am able to do both of these tasks.
**The problem**: 
After converting to video, when I run it on vlc, it seems to be working fine(Original colors, valid audio).
 When I check the video in Twitter, it appears to be discolored.(though the audio is played properly)
Here is an attached image of how it looks in vlc and how it looks after being uploaded -
 [image]

I think the `ffmpeg` command I am using is wrong.
Has anyone faced similar issues after uploading to websites?

Kindly advise

Comment: could you upload your original image, too?

Comment: blind guess is that the MPEG encoder detects the still image, and moves away from standard MPEG movie encoding to something with a reduced color space or so, but that will depend on the data you feed it with.

Comment: @MarcusMüllerꕺꕺ Sorry, I missed out a part of the question which I've added in `The Problem` section. Basically it seems to work properly on vlc when running it locally.

Comment: aha! Your edit says it works properly in VLC, so maybe this is a codec incompatibility with the x264 decoder in your Chrome!

Comment: @MarcusMüllerꕺꕺ sorry, but I didn't understand :) . I don't think this has anything to do with chrome. It seems to be uniformly discolored in all browsers. I suspect it has got something to do with Twitter converting it after uploading.

Comment: ah, ok. So what I'd do is use `ffprobe` on both your uploaded file and the file that you can download from twitter (to download video files from twitter, use `youtube-dl`, should also be available from standard Ubuntu package repositories).

Comment: You can try specifying the pixel format like `-pix_fmt yuv420p`. For more information see [advanced video options](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-all.html#Advanced-Video-options).

Comment: @Chamath Thanks, It seemed to work after adding that change(I have no idea why). Can you kindly post that as an answer so that I can accept it and also, can you please elaborate why you thought of specifying the pixel format (if you want to :) )

Comment: @MarcusMüllerꕺꕺ Thanks, good to know about `ffprobe`(wished I'd known that earlier). Using that I found that the uploaded video had pixel format of - yuvj444p, while the resulting video had a pixel format of yuv420p (Which is what solved the problem) :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well here I'm converting my comment to a proper answer. When you create a video out of a image or set of images it is a good practise to specify these conflicting parameters.

> By default when using libx264, and depending on your input, ffmpeg will attempt to avoid color subsampling. Technically this is preferred, but unfortunately almost all video players, excluding FFmpeg based players, and many online video services only support the YUV color space with 4:2:0 chroma subsampling. Using the options -pix_fmt yuv420p or -vf format=yuv420p will maximize compatibility. [-doc](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Create%20a%20video%20slideshow%20from%20images)

Above explains the actual scenario and really what happened. Also keep-in-mind most of the times documentations provide solutions for your questions. Cheers!

Comment: self-answering is explicitly encouraged on StackOverflow! Here, have an upvote :)